# Jump sprite body using ccJumpto

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I have issue in jumping sprite body. Following is the update method for jumping sprite body

```
-(void) update: (ccTime) dt
{

    world->Step(dt, 10, 10);
    // BOOL worldAsleep=true;
    for(b2Body *b=world->GetBodyList();b;b=b->GetNext())
    {
        if(b->GetUserData() !=NULL)
        {

            CCSprite *myActor=(CCSprite *)b->GetUserData();


            myActor.position=ccp(b->GetPosition().x *PTM_RATIO, b->GetPosition().y *PTM_RATIO);
            b->SetTransform(b2Vec2(b->GetPosition().x,b->GetPosition().y), b->GetAngle());

           if (fire.active==YES) 
            {
                id jump=[CCJumpBy actionWithDuration:1 position:ccp(b->GetPosition().x, b->GetPosition().y) height:100 jumps:1];
                [myActor runAction:jump];
                b2Vec2 force = b2Vec2(0,350);                
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Here  fire.active is a button for jumping sprite and ccjumpto method is used for jump sprite but what to do to jump body.
For jump sprite body i was used ApplyLinearImpuls but it can not jump like sprite type.

I want to jump both sprite and body same like only sprite jump

Thanks for replay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey you jump body according to button clicked you put  below code when button clicked:

```
b2Vec2 locationWorld;
 locationWorld = b2Vec2(0.0f,8.0f);
 double Force= _body->GetMass();
  _body->ApplyLinearImpulse(Force*locationWorld, _body->GetWorldCenter());
```

Comment: I have new issue regarding jump sprite body...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190999/sprite-body-can-not-stop

Comment: hey Leena  NSLog(@"Jump Sprite");
                    b2Vec2 locationWorld;
                    locationWorld=b2Vec2(0.0f,4.0f);
                    double force=ballBody->GetMass();
                    ballBody->ApplyLinearImpulse(force*locationWorld, ballBody->GetWorldCenter()) from this code it jump only one time

Comment: I know but in my game i am using moveLeft and moveRight Button for movement of sprite and when i release move-buttons it can not stop when i can not write `else
{
      b2Vec2 force=b2Vec2(0,0);
      ballBody->SetLinearVelocity(force); 
} ` And when i write this code than jump can not perform.

Comment: Thanks for mail id and i sent you a mail please check it out.

Comment: Hey mail can not sending you. Can you give me a your personal mail id?? Or send me your test mail at leena.shah.2908@gmail.com or contact me on skype leena.shah.2908

Comment: Hey if you receive my mail then at lest reply yes so i understand that you got my mail if no then tell me here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16013/discussion-between-leena-and-user1546519)

Comment: I got the answer. I we create body and first check it is circle or polygon because circle body can not have rolling resistance so and in this case we don't need to stop manually using linearVelocity to 0. Using friction all body stop automatically excepting circle body.

Comment: Hey please refer this link and if you know then answer question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226475/create-multiple-fixtures-in-one-body