# Create multiple fixtures in one body

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

[image]

I want to create this types of Fixture in one body. Here square and circle both are different fixtures but attach in one body

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use number of tools to make the fixtures. At my best knowledege there are some Tools listed as follows

**[Physics Editor](http://www.codeandweb.com/)**

**[Vertex Helper](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/vertexhelper-pro/id411684411?mt=12)**

**[Sprite Helper](http://www.spritehelper.org/)**

**[Level Helper](http://www.levelhelper.org/)**

There might be more tools for physics editor, but I would prefer to use Physics Editor.

Comment: All these are paid version so any another method for creating this types of fixtures??

Comment: Probably Physics Editor is Free. Other one is to make shape by your own code for creating square and circle.

Comment: But i could not find it free. If you have than can you mail me on leena.shah.2908@gmail.com??